# Mailcore: Inexpensive way to get message summary

Tags: mailcore2

I know I can get a plain text version of a message using `plainTextRenderingOperationWithMessage:` but it's very time consuming. I'm only trying to put together a short message summary. Is there a way to get this from the MCOIMAPMessage/MCOAbstractPart without using `plainTextRenderingOperationWithMessages:`?

I've got a semi-working solution with the following code but it still seems slow (about 2 seconds for the operation to complete) considering all the data should be contained in MCOIMAPMessage which is fully downloaded. Is this as fast as it gets or am I missing something?

```
    MCOIMAPMessage *m = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.email.mcomessage];
    MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation * op =
    [session fetchMessageAttachmentByUIDOperationWithFolder:folder
                                                        uid:[m uid]
                                                     partID:@"1"
                                                   encoding:MCOEncoding8Bit];

    [op start:^(NSError * error, NSData * partData) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:partData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        string = [string mco_strippedWhitespace];
        if (string.length > 200) string = [string substringToIndex:200];
        NSLog(@"String: %@", string);

    }];
```

Comment: you can investigate -[MCOIMAPMessage htmlRenderingWithFolder:delegate:]. It will be still slow but you can work things out by using caching.

Comment: What do I return from the dataForIMAPPart delegate method?

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Never mind, I solved my problem another way.

Comment: how have you solved it?